Internal Server Error When Uploading Image in Flutter
I am trying to upload an image to the server using the API endpoint that is working fine in Postman.
Here is the Dart Method.
Future<void> uploadImage(String imagePath) async {
  File file = File(imagePath);

  if (!await file.exists()) {
    return;
  }
  var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse('My Endpoint URL'));
  request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('image', imagePath));

  http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
  } else {
    print(response.reasonPhrase);
  }
}

Usage:
Future<void> _onConvertToSticker(ConvertToSticker event, Emitter<FaceToStickerState> emit) async {
  emit(FaceToStickerState(image: event.image, isLoading: true));
  print("Image path: ${event.image.path}");
  final filePath = event.image.path;
  await uploadImage(filePath);
}

In postman the body is a form-data with an attribute image as shown in the image below:

Any help with be appreciated.

what is the response.statusCode that you get?

it is 500 status code

That normally indicates on the server side.  Since you don't get that with Postman, double check that the POST you're making in Flutter is really identical to what you're generating in Postman.  In the past when I've faced problems like this, I'll use webhook.site, and send the POST to it instead of your actual server.  Do that for both Postman and your app.   WebHook.site provides detailed logs so you can see exactly what the server received.

I've fixed the issue, I was not allowing some image extensions in the API.
